# Python like sed using regexes

Tags: python, regex, sed

Let's say, that I have:

```
string= '{'id': '1'}'
```

and now using strings like in Perl/sed I would like to get

```
string=id
```

(in Perl it would look like `string=~s/\{\'([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\'.*$)/\1/`)

Could you please give me a little insight how to do that in python? I expect that the regex syntax will be similar, but I'm not sure about the python syntax and what imports should I use, I'm quite beginner in Python :) Thank you a lot :-)

Comment: It's not clear if the first snippet is meant to be a string or python code. Either way I think you either have too many single quotes in it or need to escape the inner ones.

Comment: Why would you need to use regex?? Is the `string` a proper JSON formatted string? `import json\n jsonDict = json.loads(strVariable) strID = jsonDict['id']`

Comment: to clarify: i have following code:string = child.attrib (now in string i have {'id': '1'} ) and I'm trying to get only the attribute name using regexes, so in the very same variable string i would have only id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you'd use the `re` module for regular expression operations.  I modified your regular expression a bit, but generally, this is how regular expression replacement can be done in python:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "{'id': '1'}"
>>> re.sub(r"{'([^\']*)'.*$", r'\1', string)
'id'
```

The `sub()` function accepts the regex first, then the replacement and finally the string. The documentation of the re module has some more information: 
http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

The `r` prefix to the strings passed as arguments basically tells Python to treat them as "raw" strings, where most backslash escape sequences are not interpreted.

Comment: thanks, that's what i was looking for :-)
but i have one more not really related question -> i get my string from element.attrib (using elementtree), but it's not a string so i cant pass it to re.sub... is there any way how can i convert it to string?

Comment: You can use the `str()` method to convert Python objects to a string representation. If you use the `element.attrib()` method though, you basically get a python dictionary, so that string manipulation is probably not the best way to process that information to start with. If you're just interested in what attributes are defined on your element, you could call `element.attrib().keys()` to get a list of all attribute names.

Comment: keeeeyyyys, I knew that I used stg like that once.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I agree with @PenguinCoder: since this is valid JSON, you should really think about just using the Python support for handling JSON.

I went to Google and typed in the keywords:  `Python regular expressions`

Here are the top two hits:

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html

If you read them you will find the answer.

Here's working code:

```
import re

s = '''string= "{'id': '1'}"'''

pat = re.compile(r"\s*([^=]+)\s*=[\s'\"]*{\s*'([^']+)'")

m = pat.match(s)

if m is not None:
    id = m.group(1)
    name = m.group(2)
    result = "%s=%s" % (id, name)
    # note: could also do this: result = "%s=%s" % m.groups()
```